# App Validation Error around code-signing, errUnknownFormat

Tags: ios, xcode

Codesigning Failure when I hit 'Validate' in Organizer on the Archive I just built. The provisioning profile matches the app identifier and is for the App Stop (not ad hoc). The archive builds correctly. I've downloaded and chosen the correct profile in both places, the project and the target.

In console I see:

```
6/12/12 3:43:08.720 PM Xcode: SecCertificateCopyCommonName returned -25257
```

and

```
6/12/12 3:37:18.600 PM Xcode: SecIdentityCopyCertificate returned -25257
```

perusing the source code i see that -25257 refers to errUnknownFormat. And the 'Sec' in front of those calls is the security base code, so it does actually seem that it is the code-signing that isn't working.

This was happening in XCode 4.3.2, and I just upgraded to 4.3.3 and it is still happening. I'm downloading 4.2.1 to see if it happens there or not.

In addition I also see this in console:

```
6/12/12 3:37:55.893 PM Xcode: /Users/jobelenus/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-06-12/Freedom 6-12-12 3.28 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Freedom.app/www/project-assets/627/2011/06: Is a directory
```

From searching around (mostly on SO) the "Is a directory" problem relates to a bug in XCode 4.3 with child/parent directories having the same name. From the above error you can see that is not true. There is no other directory in the app with 2011, 06, or 627, in any of the trees. There are no duplicates.

Comment: seems the -25257 error code is a red herring... found another directory problem.. hoping this solves it.

Comment: Hi John. Have you managed to find a resolution? I'm having the same issue.